# Video/image out of focus using back camera on Samsung with Media Capture and Streams API

Tags: focus, media, capture, samsung

I am using the Media Capture and Streams API in an application (the goal is to make a photo of a drivers license). I am running into the problem that using the back facing camera on Samsung phones (I have so far tries the S20 and S22) the camera doesn't focus correctly (or I should I say at all) and it's impossible to get a clear photo. Oddly enough, the user facing camera works perfect, which is also the case with the built in camera app (both camera's)!

I am basically using the code from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Capture_and_Streams_API/Taking_still_photos which can be easily used to reproduce the issue.

I have been searching for two days now to find a solution but no luck so far. Any ideas?